# Updating a Label when Combobox Selection changes

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, combobox

I'm trying to update a label when the combo box selection is changed so that it presents a count from a query. Unless I specify suing a  string the where clause, it wont let me use the value from the combobox.SelectedValue, it returns a zero.

```
where (o.ShipCountry == "USA")
```

And what I've been trying:

```
private void cmbCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ord = (from o in db.Orders
                   where (o.ShipCountry == cmbCountry.SelectedValuePath)
                   select o.ShipCountry).Count();

        lblOrders.Content = ord;
    }
```

Here's a screen of the issue to help. The zero should be a count of all the orders to a certain country specified by the combo box.[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is `ShipCountry == Belgium`? I mean, it contains countries name?

Comment: ShipCountry could be any country from the Orders table.

Comment: When you get to the function what is the value of `cmbCountry.SelectedValuePath`

Comment: Have you tried `o.ShipCountry == cmbCountry.SelectedValue.ToString()`?

Comment: I tried that previous to this.  @BugFinder using cmbCountry.SelectedValuePath actually would work. I was using an anonymous type in the query used to populate the combobox! The value path would have been `SelectedValue.cc` if I'm correct? The cc because the anonymous type was `select new { cc = c.Country}` for the query used to fill the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realized my problem!
The LINQ query I used to populate the ComboBox used an anonymous type to reference the column being selected. I named it "cc".

```
var cmb = (from c in db.Customers
                   orderby c.Country descending
                   select new { cc = c.Country }).Distinct();
```

Which meant the binding path was `Binding Path=SelectedValue.cc`

```
var cmb = (from c in db.Customers
               orderby c.Country descending
               select c.Country).Distinct();
```

By removing the anonymous type I was able to access the SelectedValue of the combobox.